# lookup another lookup

Tags: 2010, lookup-column

I've 3 lists. List B looks up List A and then I need to create a lookup in List C that lookups List B  but also get values in List B that are lookups of List A.

How is this achievable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There no problem to show additional fields of lookup list in List C.
When you're adding lookup field to List C just select additional fields from List B that you want to show in List C.

Comment: Hi The additional fields are not available to List C as those fields are lookups from List A (or at least Projected Fields). This is what the problem is.

Comment: Try to use calculated field to get value from lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, what you need to do is use a cascading lookup field (a custom field that enables filtering one lookup according to the value[s] selected in the parent loookup. Then you can set up two lookup columns in your Features list, the first looking up the Initiatives list, the other - Themes list. Once you select a value in the Initiative, only the relevant values are available in Theme.

An example of a field like this is http://infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=ConnectedFields2007, but there are other solutions as well.

Comment: Hi In List C I just want to make available (or copy) the Lokkups in List B.