# Lookup to Person Picker field

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, person

I'm trying to do a lookup to a person picker field in another list, but SP2013 won't show me that column. Any thoughts on how to bypass that?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint functionality won't allow you to do this.  What you are trying to do is lookup a lookup field (People/Group field is really a lookup).

This question also goes over the same idea: [lookup another lookup](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142006/lookup-another-lookup).